# In this scenario, why does Alias work, but AliasMatch fail?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-alias

When trying to match this code:

```
Alias /assets/ "/home/virtual/public_assets/"
AliasMatch ^/~([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/assets/(.*)$     /home/virtual/public_assets/$2

AllowOverride All
```

to the following URI

```
/~admin30/assets/js/tests.js
```

the `Alias` directive works for our live sites, but `AliasMatch`, which is supposed to match user directories, does not work.  What is wrong with the `AliasMatch` here?

Comment: So there are no user directories in `/home/virtual/public_assets`? What if two users have the same file path (i.e. `/~admin31/assets/js/tests.js`).  In your case they would both map to `/home/virtual/public_assets/js/tests.js`. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: That is correct. I would like to have a common folder shared between multiple accounts for common resources.

Comment: So what is not working with it? Can you say what behavior you are getting? Does your web server have proper permissions on that directory?

Comment: Apache should route http://www.domain.com/~user/assets/js/tests.js to an internal common directory which is /home/virtual/public_assets/js/tests.js but this is not happening. And yes the permissions are set correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Apache logs?  The AliasMatch rule seems fine to me.

Comment: [Wed Jan 23 09:58:18 2013] [error] [client <IP ADDRESS>] File does not exist: /home/virtual/site99/fst/var/www/html/assets

...maybe I don't understand the Alias directive?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23242/discussion-between-mkultra-and-mike-brant)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having same issue.

Comment: I don't believe I did ever get this resolved :( Good luck with this one. If you can figure it out, please post as a solution (And sorry for the delayed response)